# Freestyle rendering problem (REALLY big gaps/"fur")

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

Okay, so I have this cartoon rabbit Im working on. I've set up the freestyle rendering so that it used to look like this:
[image: 1]

Had tiny gaps but I could live with it. Now, I made some kind of small change (Im still not sure what exactly caused this, but Im pretty sure I didnt modify my freestyle settings), and now it looks like this:

[image: 2]

I can fix that a liiiitle bit by disabling the "Face Smoothness" option, but it still looks terrible:

[image: 3]

Can anyone help me fix this bug? I looked around on the internet, but no one has had a freestyle gap problem quite this bad or even similar to this. The usual "huge gaps" people complain seem quite tiny in comparison. Unfortunately I dont have any backups of the old version (that tpose render is all I got of), or else I could backtrack or compare what went wrong...

Comment: As always: In this case, consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it. I would guess you have double vertices or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Grimm was right, I had double vertices, I must have duplicated the model accidentally! This is solved now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's great. So please, mark your answer as *accepted* so this topic is complete.